# Need help using a filter on the default Categories widget

Tags: widgets, filters, categories

I need to add the "All Categories" item to the default WP categories widget.

I can see that there's a filter that I can hook into in the core (line 485 default-widgets.php).

```
wp_list_categories(apply_filters('widget_categories_args', $cat_args));
```

I've written the following function, but I must have something wrong as it's not adding the all categories item to the list.

```
// Add "All Categories" to categories widget
function add_all_categories_to_widget($cat_args) {
    $cat_args['show_option_all'] = 'yes';
    return $cat_args;
}
add_filter('widget_categories_dropdown_args', 'add_all_categories_to_widget');
```

Can anyone fill me in on what I've got wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I was just hooking into the wrong filter. My `add_filter` should have hooked into `widget_categories_args` not `widget_categories_dropdown_args`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on Gus's answer so that there's a full code snippet for whoever searches for it.

You need to hook into the [`widget_categories_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/widget_categories_args/) filter like this:

```
add_filter('widget_categories_args', 'add_view_all_to_categories_widget');
function add_view_all_to_categories_widget($args) {
    $args['show_option_all'] = 'View All';
    return $args;
}
```